# Automatically setup a Asp.net Core developer environment with IIS hosting/debugging

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I have a Powershell script that builds and sets up several web applications on a developer machine. It is used when first setting up a development environment or when a developer wants to simply get the latest version of everything and make it available on their machine. Usually to work on one particular app, but having all the others available since they provide services to each other.

For "old" Asp.net applications, this is as simple as building the .csproj and pointing a site on the local IIS to the appropriate folder.

For our new .Net Core applications, it looked just as simple for a while. The script built the appropriate .csproj using Msbuild, and created and configured an AppPool and IIS Site pointing to the project directory using Powershell. The web.config file contains `<aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" />` to enable IIS hosting and debugging.

This approach worked on computers that had already run the .net Core apps in question. However, it turns out that `bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe` is *not* created during the build by MsBuild, but only when launching the app for the first time within Visual Studio. This means that, even though everything is properly setup, new developers would still have to manually open each solution and launch each one of the installed apps manually from Visual Studio for their environment to be properly and entirely setup.

Has anyone had any luck automating this process ?

I know that developing .Net Core apps directly on the local IIS server is not a "preferred" scenario, but automatically installing and running multiple web apps that form part of a SOA on demand seems reasonable.

Last, but not least, I'd like to point out that we're trying to set up a *development* environment, where a developer is supposed to be able to open a solution in Visual Studio and the app(s) that it contains are ready to be debugged on the local IIS. So simply publishing the apps to a local site is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar, and ended up writing a script (below) to generate the needed files.  It has VERY basic .csproj file support, so if it doesn't work, you can provide absolute paths to the `-WorkingDirectory` and `-AssemblyPath` parameters instead.  It sets the bare minimum parameters needed to run the site without opening Visual Studio first.  Once someone builds/starts debugging in Visual Studio, the files will be overwritten, and debugging will work as expected.

This uses the [VSSetup](https://github.com/microsoft/vssetup.powershell) PowerShell module to automatically detect which version of Visual Studio you have installed (works with 2017 or higher).

#### VSIISExeLauncher shim script:

```
# This utilizes https://github.com/microsoft/vssetup.powershell
# Quick setup:  Install-Module VSSetup -Scope CurrentUser

param(
    [string] $WorkingDirectory = "",
    [string] $AssemblyPath = "",
    [string] $ProjectPath = "",
    [string] $Build = "Debug"
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Check that at parameter requirements are met
if ((-not $WorkingDirectory -and -not $ProjectPath) -or (-not $AssemblyPath -and -not $ProjectPath)) {
    throw "Please specify the working directory and assembly path, or the project file name"
}

# Get assembly path and working directory information using .csproj file
if ($ProjectPath) {
    $project = [xml] (Get-Content $ProjectPath -Raw)
    if ($project.Project.Sdk -ine "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web") {
        throw "$ProjectPath is not a Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web project"
    }

    $TargetFramework = "$($project.Project.PropertyGroup.TargetFramework)".Trim()
    $RootNamespace = "$($project.Project.PropertyGroup.RootNamespace)".Trim()
    $WorkingDirectory = (Get-Item $ProjectPath).Directory.FullName
    $AssemblyPath = "$WorkingDirectory\bin\$Build\$TargetFramework\$RootNamespace.dll"
    if (-not (Test-Path $AssemblyPath)) {
        $AssemblyPath = "$WorkingDirectory\bin\$TargetFramework\$RootNamespace.dll"

        if (-not (Test-Path $AssemblyPath)) {
            throw "Could not find $AssemblyPath"
        }
    }
}

# Get the newest version of Visual Studio installed on this machine
Import-Module VSSetup
$VSSetup = (Get-VSSetupInstance | Sort-Object { $_.InstallationVersion } -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)

# Build some path strings
$VSIISExePath = "$($VSSetup.InstallationPath)\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe"
$DotNetPath = (Get-Command dotnet).Source
$IISSupportPath = "bin\IISSupport"

# For debugging purposes
Write-Host "Working Directory: $WorkingDirectory"
Write-Host "Assembly Path:     $AssemblyPath"
Write-Host "VSIISEXELauncher:  $VSIISExePath"
Write-Host "DotNet:            $DotNetPath"

# Create the support folder and copy needed files
Push-Location $WorkingDirectory

mkdir -Force $IISSupportPath | Out-Null
Copy-Item $VSIISExePath $IISSupportPath

@"
-p $DotNetPath
-pidFile $WorkingDirectory\$IISSupportPath\pidfile.txt
-wd $WorkingDirectory
-a exec `"$AssemblyPath`"
-env ASPNETCORE_CONTENTROOT=$WorkingDirectory`0COMPLUS_ForceENC=1`0ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`0
"@ | Set-Content "$IISSupportPath\IISExeLauncherArgs.txt"

# Show the list of files as proof the command completed
Get-ChildItem $IISSupportPath

Pop-Location
```

#### IIS Site Creation:

A side note related to your last paragraph, if you're looking for a way to set up IIS sites, take a look at the [WebAdministration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/) PowerShell module.  You can easily create sites, set their bindings, add/configure app pools, and set web.config options.  IIS settings will also show up as a drive in PowerShell (`IIS:\`) for easily accessing settings using `New-Item`, `Get-Item`, etc.

Also, take a look at the [Carbon](http://get-carbon.org/) PowerShell module, which can be used for easily setting host entries without manually modifying the hosts file.  It's also available on [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).